# unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps

Tags: android, android-activity, dictionary

E/PackageManager(78): Package com.bountouris requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.maps; failing!

this is my log file. My app before it works. I have not change anything about map.

EDIT:

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" > 
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> 
<activity android:name=".Syros1Activity" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter> 
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /> 
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</activity> 
<activity android:name=".MyMapActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" 
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
</activity>
```

Comment: don't post code in the comments. edit your question if you want to add code. And use the source formatting.

Comment: Do you use emulator or device? Make sure you use emulator and SDK with Google APIs, not plain Android.

Answer (score 5):

It happens that your code uses GoogleAPIs. 
Right-click your project -> Run As -> Run Configuration..., in the target tab -> Select appropriate Android Virtual Device which has GoogleAPIs.(like GoogleAPIs - Platform 2.3.3).

Apply -> Run.

Answer (score 0):

Launch the AVD Manager by using the android command without any options. If you are developing in Eclipse/ADT, you can also access the tool from Window > Android SDK and AVD Manager.

Click the "New" button to begin creating a new AVD.
In the dialog that appears, specify a name for the AVD and select the system image target that you want the AVD to use. Select one of the "Google APIs (Google Inc.)" targets, making sure to choose a version whose API Level matches the android:minSdkVersion attribute in your application's manifest, as described above.
Configure the other options and then click "Create AVD".
Once you've finished creating the AVD, you can run it from the AVD Manager UI or you can use the emulator's command-line interface. If you are developing in Eclipse, you can configure a Run Configuration to start the AVD and install your application on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing this from manifest file:

```
   <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true"/>
```